# Rails - Model name ends with S

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I have a model named `ActiveDns`.  When I run

```
rails g scaffold_controller ActiveDns
```

I get the message

> Plural version of the model detected, using singularized version. Override with --force-plural.

Now, the controller and views are generated pretending that the singular is `ActiveDn` and the plural is `ActiveDns`, and I get silly stuff like `link_to new_dn_path`.  The `--force-plural` argument doesn't appear to fix this:

```
rails g scaffold_controller ActiveDns --force-plural
```

still results in controllers using variables named `@active_dn` and views using `new_dn_path`, with rails 3.2.3.  I am removing files between tries using `rails d scaffold_controller ActiveDns`.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Instead of removing the incorrect files manually, you can also just `rails destroy scaffold_controller ActiveDns`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What's the right way to do this?

I use [inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-inflections) to [document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting) uncountable entities.

> config/initializers/inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable "ActiveDns"
end
```

Then you get:

```
$ rails g scaffold_controller ActiveDns
      create  app/controllers/active_dns_controller.rb
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/active_dns
      create    app/views/active_dns/index.html.erb
      create    app/views/active_dns/edit.html.erb
      create    app/views/active_dns/show.html.erb
      create    app/views/active_dns/new.html.erb
      create    app/views/active_dns/_form.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/functional/active_dns_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/active_dns_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/unit/helpers/active_dns_helper_test.rb
```

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 16):

I tested with rails-3.2 (I guess it should work with rails-3.x)

Open your `config/initializers/inflections.rb` and add a rule:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'dns', 'dnses'
end
```

And generate the controller

```
rails g scaffold_controller ActiveDns
```

And add routes to your `config/routes.rb` file

```
resources :active_dnses
```

Then you should see:

```
$ rake routes

   active_dnses GET    /active_dnses(.:format)          active_dnses#index
                POST   /active_dnses(.:format)          active_dnses#create
 new_active_dns GET    /active_dnses/new(.:format)      active_dnses#new
edit_active_dns GET    /active_dnses/:id/edit(.:format) active_dnses#edit
     active_dns GET    /active_dnses/:id(.:format)      active_dnses#show
                PUT    /active_dnses/:id(.:format)      active_dnses#update
                DELETE /active_dnses/:id(.:format)      active_dnses#destroy
```

Comment: Works fine for me with rails 4.2.1

Comment: had the same issue with "status" under rails 5

Comment: This solution almost worked for me, with exception of route helper methods. Alhought `rake routes` begaves correctly, the method `new_active_dns_path` does not exist, only `new_active_dnses_path` does, which is strange. Also the method `form_for(@active_dns)` keeps pluralizing in a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

> I want to share about how I solve my problem.

I have an MVC with a name of `Pacman` under `Data_Warehouse`.

Where `Pacman` is a proper noun. (Cannot be `Pacmen` with an `e`, but should be `Pacmans` with an `s`)

And `Data_Warehouse` is like a platform name. (Could be anything, in this case its `DataWarehouse::Pacman`)

So, I have

Models name - `models/data_warehouse/pacman.rb`

Views name - `views/data_warehouse/pacmans/index.slim`

Controller name - `controller/data_warehouse/pacmans_controller.rb`

The problem is, Rails read this path

`data_warehouse_pacmans_path`

as

`data_warehouse_pacmen_path`

because of pluralization.

So

I solved this by adding

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
   inflect.uncountable %w( pacmans )
end
```

to the `inflections.rb` file in Rails.

> Hope this would helps

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit the question with details that is only relevant to the question you ask (avoid describing your details in the post). You can always use the edit function to update your question.